# Laravel implicit model binding omit parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using implicit model binding in Laravel 5.3.26 for routes like this

`POST /teams/{team}/customers/{customer}/addresses`

The `{team}` is used in a middleware to determine which team the user is currently using. However the store method for the addresses only needs the `{customer}` injected; it does not access the team in any way. So the header of the method could look like this:

```
public function store(Customer $customer, Request $request)
```

Unfortunately the id of the selected team gets injected into `$customer` instead of the actual `Customer` instance. If I add the `$team` parameter to the store method, so the function header would look like this:

```
public function store(Team $team, Customer $customer, Request $request)
```

everything works as expected. Is there a way to omit the `$team` parameter but still get the correct `Customer` instance injected into the function ?

Comment: how about `/customers/{customer}/addresses?team=2`? cos it looks like you are trying to get the address of customer at a particular id and team info looks like some additional data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just make a different route for this:

```
Route::put('customers', 'CustomerController@store')-name('customers.store');
```

Then your form:

```
<form action="{{ route('customers.store') }}' method="POST">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    //other stuff
</form>
```

Alternatively, if you must, you can just use a `?` in the route to dictate that the model may or may not be present:

```
Route::post('/teams/{team?}/customers/{customer}/addresses', 'Controller@method');
```

Then in your controller method, you'd still have to define `$team`, but it may or may not exist, such as:

```
public function store(Request $request, $team = null, Customer $customer)
```

**Side Note** `Request` should always come first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might not have made that clear enough: the team route parameter is mandatory. I simply don't need it in my controller, but it's being used somewhere else. Thats the reason why I want to omit the `$team` parameter from my controller's store method, because I'll never gonna use it there and it feels/looks kind of weird to inject a parameter if you don't use it.

Comment: @Tobias Ah! Thank you for the clarification. Given the design of your system, I would recommend you ensure that it is there. This is a design pattern, and by no means do I feel it is incorrect.